# Flutter getx controller get the current page context

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I would like to use context to show a custom dialog from cool alert in getxcontroller method.
I have created the following controller

```
class HomePageController extends GetxController {
 
   @override
   void onInit() {
     super.onInit();
     getData();
   }

   void getData(){
    //perform http request here 
     //show cool alert 

     CoolAlert.show(
      context: context,  //here needs the build context
      type: CoolAlertType.success
      );
   }

}
```

Am using this controller in my stateless widget like

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   HomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

   final _c = Get.find<HomePageController>();


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
  
          );
    }
 }
```

How can i get the current homepage BuildContext in the controller inorder to show the cool alert.

Comment: Initialize HomePageController on HomePage  if you want access to the current screen context

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: // You can get the context here
   BuildContext? context = Get.context;

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show a dialog or snackbar what need context as a required agument. You can use `Get.dialog()` and `Get.snackbar`, there function work same as `showDialog` and `showSnackbar` but `*without*` context or scaffod

Answer (score 1):

you can add the context to the construct function:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Get.put(HomePageController(context: context));
  return Container();
}
```

and for the HomePageController:
**note**: you need to wrap the function with   `Future.delayed(Duration.zero)`
otherwise it will throw an error

```
class HomePageController extends GetxController {
  late BuildContext context;

  HomePageController({required this.context});
  
   void getData(){
     Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
       CoolAlert.show(
         context: context,  //here needs the build context
         type: CoolAlertType.success
       );
     });
   }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use

```
Get.context
```

It will look like something like this

```
class HomePageController extends GetxController {
 
   @override
   void onInit() {
     super.onInit();
     getData();
   }

   void getData(){
    //perform http request here 
     //show cool alert 

     CoolAlert.show(
      context: Get.context,  //here needs the build context
      type: CoolAlertType.success
      );
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent Dart has null Value in order to compensate the null Value Use ! mark:
So in this Case We're using this:

Get.context!

Answer (score -2):

You Need to Initialize the controller on the homepage like following

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   HomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

   final _c = Get.put(HomePageController())..getData(context);


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
  
          );
    }
 }
```

This will call getData Function and remove the onInit Function and Pass Buildcontext context parameter in getData Function.

Comment: How will i pass the context to the controller?

Comment: @Geoff I have changed my answer check that.